# what makes a simple program to be a good program?

Tags: logic

The programming language or The programming logic.....

Because both are equally important for good coding practice. And, please justify your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What makes a program to be a good program?

**Being able to address the customer needs and make him happy.**

Programming language, programming logic, code style etc. are nonessential to the success.

Comment: consider from developer's point of view, not as a end user's point of view.

Comment: Most customer doesn't care programming language or logic.

Comment: From a developer's point of view, the answer is: Being able to address the customer needs and make him happy, because he pays you for that.

Comment: This is my developer's point of view as well.

Answer (score 1):

The programming language doesn't have squat to do with a good program, you can write ugly code in C++ and  elegant code in LOLcode and if they perform the same function nobody will care. Most important is that the code is bug free and performs its function.